# In the Recursion method below, do all individual list references point to the same individual List object on the Heap? - C#

Tags: c#, list, recursion, stack-memory

Following is the code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    Recursion(list);
}

public static void Recursion(List<int> list = null)
{
    if (list.Count == 3)
        return;
    list.Add(1);
    Recursion(list);
}
```

At the end of all the recursive calls of the `Recursion` method, there will be **4** stack frames of the `Recursion` method on the Stack:
[image: Call Stack]

Each stack frame will contain a `list` pointer (`list` parameter), that points to the same single `list` object on the Heap. So on the stack, there will be 4 Activation Records, one each for the `Recursion` method. And, each Activation Record will have the `list` pointer which will point to the same `List` object on the Heap.

This is because we are passing the initial `list` pointer from `Main()` into the Recursion method and the initial `list` pointer points to an object on the Heap (when we do `var list=new List<int>()` in `Main()`).
So the `list` pointer in `Main()` points to an object on the Heap.
When `Recursion` method is called from `Main()`, the `list` pointer (`list` reference) that points to the object on heap is copied to the `list` parameter of Recursion (which is initially `null`), the very first time.
So both the `list` pointer in `Main()` and the `list` parameter of the Recursion method point to the same `List` object on the Heap.

Next, we are in the `Recursion` method and now `Recursion` method calls itself the first time.
So, when calling the `Recursion` method this time, again the same thing takes place. Meaning, when we call `Recursion(list)`, a new Activation Record for Recursion method is created on the Stack and, the instantiated `list` pointer in `Recursion(list)` is copied into the `list` parameter of the new Activation Record for the `Recursion` method (please note that this `list` parameter of the new Activation Record was also originally `null`).

**Thus, at the end of all the recursive calls to the `Recursion` method, there are `5` distinct `list` pointers on the Stack - one for each Activation Record. And each of these `list` pointers point to the same `List` object on the Heap.**

I believe my understanding is correct. Or is it flawed at some point? Any light on this will be highly appreciated.

Also, I have been told that methods live in the code segment. But if methods live in the code segment, how do recursive methods work? It is hard to imagine that part of the method lives in the code segment and part of the method lives on the Stack. Any light on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: short answer - yes

Comment: `methods live in the code segment` really applies only to native code - for managed code, as we have here, the actual executable code is (usually) generated at run-time by the just-in-time compiler on demand, but this is besides the point: what's on the stack is not code but data anyway, so it's irrelevant to the present discussion where the code is actually located.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, can you please tell me where is the executable code (that is, the method) stored in C# (since it is not stored in the code segment)? Thanks!

Comment: Where the code is in memory is unrelated to the question of where the list is (or how many instances there are). it doesn't matter -- the compiler and runtime do the right thing. Explaining how managed code execution and JIT work is complex. (e.g. managed code can be interpreted from IL without jitting it).

Comment: The microprocessor has segment registers and code segment and stack segment are two of the segment registers.  Microsoft doesn't really document very well how the compiler actually works.  The last time I've seen any good documentation was in the earlier 1990's.  So of the structure still exist but not very well documented.  Old compiler there were two data areas.  One for static data and the other for dynamic data (stack).  I think what you are referring is the variable defined in Main which uses static data and dynamic is the hash/stack data.  A list is not hash.  Hash is a dictionary.

Comment: @jdweng The discussion is C# not C++, so it's actually pretty well documented (and open source). There are many articles online about the C# compiler, as well as the JITter.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I am talking about the list variable that is instantiated in Main. That list variable lives on the Stack and points to the List object on the Heap. When that list pointer is passed to the Recursion method, a new stack frame is created on the Stack for Recursion method. And the list pointer that is passed from Main is copied to the list parameter of Recursion method in the new stack frame. Thus, at the end of all the recursive calls to the `Recursion` method, there are `5` distinct `list` pointers on the Stack - OneForEachActivationRecord. AndThesePointToTheSameListObjectOnTheHeap.